# .NET: Get all classes derived from specific class

Tags: .net, oop, reflection, inheritance, attributes

I have a custom control and a number of controls derived from it. 
I need to get all classes in the current assembly that are derived from the main class and check their attributes.
How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var type = typeof(MainClass);

var listOfDerivedClasses = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(type))
    .ToList();

foreach (var derived in listOfDerivedClasses)
{
   var attributes = derived.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TheAttribute), true);

   // etc.
}
```

Comment: Just to note, an assumption is being made in the above code that MainClass is in the current executing assembly (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly).  If it is not, you will have a problem.

Comment: @Brady, not true. This code looks for types in the currently executing assembly that are derived from MainClass -- which can be in the same assembly or a different one: it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection:

```
Type baseType = ...
var descendantTypes =
    from type in baseType.Assembly.GetTypes()
    where !type.IsAbstract
       && type.IsSubclassOf(baseType)
       && type.IsDefined(typeof(TheCustomAttributeYouRequire), true)
    select type;
```

You can go from there.

Comment: Why !type.IsAbstract?  An abstract class can still be a class derived from another class.

Answer (score 0):

To find derivatives of a class, which were all defined in another Assembly (GetExecutingAssembly didn't work), I used:

```
var asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass));
var listOfClasses = asm.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyClass)));
```

(split over 2 lines to save scrolling)